# asp.net mvc 3 moq n-tier test - Object not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, moq, structuremap

I have the following test that is constantly failing and I cant work out why :(

```
[TestClass]
public class UserTest
{
    private Mock<IRolodexDA> _rmock = new Mock<IRolodexDA>();
    private Mock<ICompanyDA> _cmock = new Mock<ICompanyDA>();
    private Mock<IUserSettingsDA> _umock = new Mock<IUserSettingsDA>();
    private Mock<ICLObjectContext> _clmock = new Mock<ICLObjectContext>();


    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Inject(typeof(IRolodexDA), _rmock.Object);
        ObjectFactory.Inject(typeof(ICompanyDA), _cmock.Object);
        ObjectFactory.Inject(typeof(IUserSettingsDA), _umock.Object);
        ObjectFactory.Inject(typeof(ICLObjectContext), _clmock.Object);
    }


[TestMethod]
public void Get_does_not_return_valid_user_when_not_enabled()
{

        string email_add = "theguy@totest.com";
        List<RolodexDomain> items = new List<RolodexDomain>();
        items.Add(new RolodexDomain() {rdx_contact_name = "joe blogs", rdx_auto_key = 1, email_address = email_add, cv_udf_030 = null , sdf_rdx_001 = null });


        _rmock.Setup(s => s.Get()).Returns(items.AsQueryable());

        var result2 = _rmock.Object.Get();

        var user = new CLAPortal.Service.UserService();
        var result = user.Get(email_add);

        Assert.IsNull(result);

}
```

In my service layer I have the following code:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IRolodexDA _rolodexDA = Resolver.GetConcreteInstanceOf<IRolodexDA>();
    private readonly IUserSettingsDA _userSettingsDA = Resolver.GetConcreteInstanceOf<IUserSettingsDA>();
    private readonly ICompanyDA _companyDA = Resolver.GetConcreteInstanceOf<ICompanyDA>();
    private ICLObjectContext _context = Resolver.GetConcreteInstanceOf<ICLObjectContext>();

    public UserDomain Get(string email_address)
    {
        UserDomain user = null;
        var rdx = GetRolodexForUser(email_address);

        if (rdx != null)
        {
            user = new UserDomain()
            {
                email_address = rdx.email_address,
                name = rdx.rdx_contact_name,
                password = rdx.sdf_rdx_001,
                rdx_auto_key = rdx.rdx_auto_key,
                settings = _userSettingsDA.Get().Where(x => x.rdx_auto_key == rdx.rdx_auto_key).SingleOrDefault() ?? null
            };
        }
        return user;
    }

    private RolodexDomain GetRolodexForUser(string email_address)
    {
        var result = (_rolodexDA.Get().Where(u => u.email_address.ToUpper() == email_address.ToUpper() && u.cv_udf_030.ToUpper() == "T"));

        return result.SingleOrDefault() ?? null;
    }
```

The issue is with the call to result in the GetRolodexForUser on the Service layer.
It gets the object not set to an instance of an object when I try to inspect the value.

Now it should be returning an empty collection in theory?

Its the only test out of my tests for this class that is failing after some refactoring, but I can't work out why :(

Any ideas?
Thanks!

PS this is my first attempt at pulling apart my app and trying to make it testable., so I may have some fundamental issue with mocking or dependancy injection i dont understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was passing in an empty string for cv udf 030 instead if null when creating my mocked get list. I am pretty sure entity framework converts nulls to empty strings